# Как разбить текст по разделителю на параграфы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получаю от сервера отзывы в `JSON`. В тексте есть разделители абзацов `\n`, но если вывести этот отзыв через `console.log()` то этих переносов нет как и в `html` когда вставляю этот текст.
Как можно разбить текст отзыва на параграфы по этому разделителю?

```
JSON
{
text: "Заказал что-то там. \nЕщё какой-то текст. \nСпасибо вам большое за работу."
}
```

Вывод консоли - переносов нет

```
Заказал что-то там. Ещё какой-то текст. Спасибо вам большое за работу.
```

Comment: а просто на css не выход ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно регулярным выражением заменить все переносы на тег переноса `<br>`

```
const text = "Заказал что-то там. \nЕщё какой-то текст. \nСпасибо вам большое за работу."
document.body.innerHTML = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Или выводить текст в теге `<pre></pre>` он сохраняет переносы и пробелы

Или разбить на массив и выводить циклом каждый параграф в новом теге `<p>`

```
const text = "Заказал что-то там. \nЕщё какой-то текст. \nСпасибо вам большое за работу.";
const p = text.split('\n');
//["Заказал что-то там. ", "Ещё какой-то текст. ", "Спасибо вам большое за работу."]
```

Comment: Привет, XSS-атака

Comment: @andreymal  как ты определяешь атаку ?